# jvectormap marker label style

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I have a world map here. http://jsfiddle.net/4sg4y64L/2/
Does anyone know how I can change the color of the labels "US" and "EU"? I tried adding the following, but am guessing those labels are NOT marker labels?

```
onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    label.html("<p style=\"color:red;\">"+ label.html()+"</p>");                
},
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "markerLabelStyle" parameter to change color of marker labels. For example, to change color to red:

```
markerLabelStyle: {
    initial: {
        // Add CSS properties here
        fill: 'red'
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4sg4y64L/4/

Comment: is it possible to add also a background shadow to make them visible also on dark regions?